# Cast a global definition in LLVM IR

Tags: casting, llvm, llvm-ir

I have two global struct type declarations, one of which is a “subtype” of the other. I want to define a global variable with the more specific type, but let the global variable have the more general type:

I tried this:

```
%hs = type { %hs* (%hs*)* }
%dc = type { %hs* (%hs*)*, i64, [1 x %hs*] }

@boring = constant %hs { %hs* (%hs*)* null }

; this works, but has type %dc* instead of %hs*
@foo = constant %dc { %hs* (%hs*)* null, i64 1, [1 x %hs*] [ %hs* @boring ] }

; this does not
@bar = constant %hs bitcast (%dc @foo to %hs)

; this tests that @bar indeed has the desired type
@test = constant %dc { %hs* (%hs*)* null, i64 1, [1 x %hs*] [ %hs* @bar ] }
```

But that fails with

```
llc-4.0: foo.ll:10:34: error: global variable reference must have pointer type
@bar = constant %hs bitcast (%dc @foo to %hs)
```

Is there a way to have `@bar` defined as above, but have type `hs*`?

Ideally in one definition?

Answer (score 0):

It works to define an alias:

```
@bar = alias %hs, %hs* bitcast (%dc* @foo to %hs*)
```

I do not know if  there is a way that does away with the intermediate value `@foo`.